# How to get url part php?

Tags: php, url, blogs

I'm trying to figure out how to edit my blog posts. I have a page which displays my current blog post. 73 in this example is the id of the post.

How can I store this 73 value into a variable in PHP based on the url ?

For example this is my url :
http://example.com/?post=73

How can I retrieve 73 and store it into a variable such as $ID = "73" ?

Comment: It will be in the `$_GET` array as `$_GET['post']`

Comment: I'm not submitting this as a form

Comment: @RyanHolmes ...that's not an excuse :D

Comment: When you load the page anything in the query string is in the `$_GET` array. Create a PHP page that has `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>` and call if something like get.php. Load the page like `http://example.com/get.php?post=73&user=owhatagooseiam` You will have two items in your get array.

Comment: Thanks Jay I understand now. I'm a begginer, I thought StackOverflow was to help people why do people have to downvote all the time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case (you have a ?var=), you need to use the GET superglobal https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

So in your case like @JayBlanchard says, use $_GET ['post'] to retrieve the 'post' value.